Meaning of "ऋतस्य श्रृंगमुर्विया विपप्रथे।"
What would be the translation of this verse and is it from rigved? Is there any commentary available for this?

ऋतस्य श्रृंगमुर्विया विपप्रथे।


Your hymn is most likely from Rigved because of its shortness and you should be able to find it under the Suktas of Varuna. You see the later Vedas tend to have longer hymns. Esp. Yajur is in Gadya shaili.   As for its meaning we can infer certain things using school level Sanskrit.
The first term is for Varuna, as the protector of laws of nature (ऋतस्य) while श्रृंगम् most probably means "peak (of a mountain)", although it could refer to a divine weapon of Indra, or simply to "horns" whereas उर्विया means "far off, widely". Your last term means "he expanded/ manifested (long, long, long ago. It is in Lit Lakār, that is a past so distant that has become a legend). Now try to unjumble it yourself! This is how Vedic Sanskrit is like, the way we use grammar now is so diverged from it, we can hardly interpret it at all. Most of the time you can find commentaries with varying interpretations due to this very reason. Yet I would suggest to think of the Vedic devatas as personifications of natural phenomena/ objects. With this, Varuna comes out as cosmic protocol for everything to function by laws of nature, otherwise be eliminated from existence.
